# Unity C# How to check IF (statement) is true for n amount of time?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have an `If` statement that returns true or false, naturally. How do I check the condition for `n` amount of time (frames, seconds)? I need the bool to return false only if condition is true for half a second.

Comment: In general please use the correct tags! Note that [`[unityscript]`](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/unityscript/info) is or better **was** a custom JavaScript flavor-like language used in early Unity versions and is **long deprecated** by now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put some code in your Update method and use a float member variable and add Time.deltaTime. The update method triggers every frame. Once the variable is over 0.5f do your magic.

```
public class MyScript : MonoBehaviour
{
    float timer:

    void Update()
    {
        // If condition is false, reset timer and return out. Replace condition with your logic.
        if (!condition)
        {
            timer = 0.0f;
            return;
        }
      
        timer += Time.deltaTime:
        if (timer > 0.5f)
        {
            // do stuff

            timer = timer - 0.5f; // reset timer
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure it's what I'm looking for. I need to check the statement for half a second, not to set a timer. 
Like, if ```this``` is true for half a second, then ```//do stuff```